# Android enviar fotos a un servidor

Tags: php, android, api, rest

seguramente hay muchos post de estos por varios lugares, he leído varios y he buscado varios ejemplos. Al no ser un experto en Android hay algunas cosas que no logro comprender, por ello hago este POST, porque lo raro es que este método que utilizo funcionaba bien. Sé que **HttpPost** y **HttpClient** ya están **deprecated** pero los tengo en varios lugares de mi aplicación y sigue funcionando.

Les pongo el código tanto del lado de Android como del lado de PHP

```
public void subirFoto(String foto){
    String miFoto = foto;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(servidor_fotos);
        File file = new File(miFoto);
        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody foto3 = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
        mpEntity.addPart("fotoUp", foto3);
        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        Log.e("sistema","FOTO SUBIDA");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("sistema","ERROR AL SUBIR LA FOTO");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Este código lo que hace es tomar las imágenes desde un directorio del dispositivo y enviarla a una url. La **url** la corroboré y es la correcta, también corroboro que encuentre la imagen en el dispositivo.

El problema es que **no la guarda en el servidor** .

El ERROR no lo tira en este código,  al contrario me dice **"foto subida"** . El problema es que no está llegando al PHP, La APP cuando está en este proceso tarda un tiempo prudencial como que está enviando la foto, pero en el PHP me tira **error de subida** y la verdad no entiendo por que.. porque estaba funcionando perfecto

Les dejo el código de PHP

```
    <?php
if ($_FILES["fotoUp"]["error"] > 0) {
    $error = "Error en el archivo: " . $_FILES["fotoUp"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
$foto = $_FILES["fotoUp"]["name"];
$total = strlen ($foto);

$file=fopen("datos.txt","w");
fputs($file,"FOTO: " . $foto . PHP_EOL);
fputs($file,"Error: ". $error . PHP_EOL);

$ruta = "fotos/" . basename( $_FILES["fotoUp"]["name"]);

try{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fotoUp"]["tmp_name"], $ruta)){
            fputs($file,"Fotos Guardada correctamente" .PHP_EOL);
           chmod ("fotos/" .basename( $_FILES["fotoUp"]["name"]), 0644);
       }else{
            fputs($file,"Imagen: " . $_FILES["fotoUp"]["tmp_name"] .PHP_EOL);
            fputs($file,"Ruta: " . $ruta .PHP_EOL);
            fputs($file,"Error al guardar la foto" .PHP_EOL);
       }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error2 =  'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
fputs($file,"Error2: ". $error2 . PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Hay algunas líneas de más porque guardo en un TXT los errores y lo que obtengo con este código es el sigueinte txt

FOTO: 
Error: 
Imagen: 
Ruta: fotos/
Error al guardar la foto
Error2:

** Es decir que nunca está llegando la foto y cuando intenta guardarla tira el error***

Ahora mi pregunta es porque no llega la foto? Reitero la URL está bien porque además se ejecuta el archivo PHP por lo tanto está llegando correctamente pero como que no llega la foto

GRACIAS