# imagen que pesa mucho no se carga

Tags: java, android

soy aprendiz y estoy chequeando un error en una app.

En un formulario se intenta cargar una imagen desde la galería o cámara. Si la imagen que se está cargando tiene un peso mayor a 8MB (aproximadamente), no se carga la imagen al servidor. La carga se realiza a través de PHP.

> Si, yo intento cargar imagenes de menor peso, si funciona bien. No hay problema con esto.

Creacion de la imagen

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir("Pictures");
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    public void camara(View v) throws IOException {


        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(public_reg2.this,
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 0);
            }
        }
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
    private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    // Return image / video
    private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == 1) { // image
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == 2) { // video
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
    public void galeria(View view) {

        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, 1);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch(requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    iv6.setImageURI(imageUri);



// For further image Upload i suppose your method for image upload is UploadImage

                    break;
                case 1:
                    try {
                        // Get uri
                        imageUri = data.getData();

                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                        int nh = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * (1024.0 / bitmap.getWidth()));
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1024, nh, true);
                        // Set image
                        iv6.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                        iv6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        a = 1;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Error el obtener la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

Carga de la imagen

```
 public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
    {
        try
        {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        }
    }
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String imagePath,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        //return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bt, reqWidth, reqHeight, false);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }



public void subir(View v){
    ImageUploadToServerFunction();

}
public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
public void ImageUploadToServerFunction(){


    InputStream iStream = null;
    try {
        iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] byteArrayVar = new byte[0];
    try {
        byteArrayVar = getBytes(iStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final String ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayVar, Base64.DEFAULT);

    class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();


            alertadd.show();
            //progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(public_reg3.this,"Cargando datos...","Por favor, espere...",false,false);
        }
```

Configuracion en PHP

```
$ImageData = $_POST['image_path'];
$dir_subida = '../img/';
$dir_img = 'https://sitioweb.com/admin/img/';

$extensiones = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp');

//Obtenemos la extensión (en minúsculas) para poder comparar

$extension = "png";

$nombre_img = $usuario .".". $extension;

$fichero_subido = $dir_subida . $nombre_img;

$dir_img = 'https://sitioweb.com/admin/img/' . $nombre_img;

//Verificamos que sea una extensión permitida, si no lo es mostramos un mensaje de error
if(!in_array($extension, $extensiones)) {
    die( 'Sólo se permiten archivos con las siguientes extensiones: '.implode(', ', $extensiones) );
```

Por otra parte, creo que es importante darles a conocer que es necesario hacer una conversión a las imagenes cargadas al servidor.  Agradecida

Comment: En tu AsyncTask no se muestra que realiza para subir la imagen, solo muestras el método onPreExecute()

Comment: Actualice, la publicacion. Cargué mas detalles.

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56312).

Comment: en vez de tratar de mandar todo como una cadena que además almacenarías en memoria, intenta mandar por pedazos o chunks usando tu stream como en esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/39099064/6999690